# Are there any optimizers that don't care about compile times?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

Are there any compilers in use that pay little attention to compilation speed but rather seek maximum optimization even at an order(s) of magnitude compile time slow down?

It seems to me that having a compile take hours/days vs minutes/second wouldn't be a major issue once you get very near the final release. (And if you have enough tests, it should be safe to.)

---

Edit: What I'm interested in are compilers that include optimization passes that can take hours or even days to run on modestly side programs (something that takes 10min or less with normal optimizations, e.g. the Linux kernel, apache or GCC its self).

Comment: For what language? I've certainly used compilers where using the optimiser takes quite a lot more time than without. Also, consider static analysers such as Coverity.

Comment: Are there any slow optimizers? Sure, they are called people!

Comment: Actually people are faster optimizers. An optimized bubble sort is still slow.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, yes. Not because the optimizer is slow, but rather because what you ask the optimizer to do is something that, of necessity, takes a long time. For example, I use LLVM to optimize whole programs: The source files that have been compiled as well as all the libraries that the source files use. Everything is linked as intermediate code and optimized together. This optimization is noticeably slower than linking separately optimized object files. But I don't care, for two reasons: 1, Optimization is done over the whole program and that is worth the wait (;-) and 2, Computers get faster all the time.

Comment: I'm not asking why they are slow, but why they aren't slower? I have the CPU, why not use it?

Comment: I'm saying you can. In my case, extreme optimization (TM) may mean the program can run on a pic32 with no external storage. Most people with 3Ghz processors and "unlimited" storage don't really care to wait for the optimizer to save them time/space.

Comment: What kind of slow down do you see? 10x?

Answer (score 2):

To some extent they are "slow", its just that the computers are so fast and possessed of such voluminous memory that you don't notice like you used to...

::Runs off to do a little experiment with g++::

Picking a slightly mathy code I wrote for work I get (about 24k LOC in c++ in 75ish files making heavy uses of the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) libraries, but no templates)

- `-O0`: 8.88 seconds
- `-O4`: 13.60 seconds
- `-Os`: 11.32 seconds

Hmm...doesn't add up to a large fraction of the compile time. Perhaps it's just dominated by file access time. Maybe I should try it with `mplayer` or something else real intensive.